# How to start up an exe with parameters

Tags: vb.net, exec, parameter-passing

I am new to Visual Basic. I am using VB Premium 2012.
Is there a way I can open/start up an `exe` file (not my app) with params. I know we can do it in batch coding using `echo` and stuff. Can it be done in vb?

I want to open up "`app.exe`" with params as "`-login usernamehere passwordhere`"

Comment: You should look at the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start [Process Start (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx#Y0)

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
Dim pHelp As New ProcessStartInfo
pHelp.FileName = "YourApplication.exe"
pHelp.Arguments = "parameter1,parameter2"
pHelp.UseShellExecute = True
pHelp.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
Dim proc As Process = Process.Start(pHelp)
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: If i use it..hwo will i use -login? the whole param is -login myusername mypassword

Comment: PHelp.Arguments="-login myusername mypassword"